# Finding a closed form expression for an integral with parametrization

Tags: integration, closed-form

Is there a general expression if the integral below is evaluated? Note that $-\infty<q<1$ where $q$ can take either integer or non-integer values; and that $b<x$ where $b,x>0$. The integral is:
$$\int_b^x \frac{1}{\left(1-(b/r)^{1-q}\right)^{1/2}}\,dr$$
The integral diverges for all values of $q<-1$, I think. I also tried feeding it up to Mathematica for every value of $q$, and the result is that for even integer values of $|q|$ except $q=-2$, the integral results to a hypergeometric function. For odd integer values of $|q|$ including $q=-2$, the integral diverges. 
Can someone help me figure this out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

By the substitution $g=(b/r)^{1-q}\implies dr=\frac{b}{q-1}g^{\frac1{q-1}-1}dg$ (and let $\frac1{q-1}-1=Q$), yielding
$$
\int_b^x \frac{1}{\left(1-(b/r)^{1-q}\right)^{1/2}}\,dr=\frac{b}{q-1}\int_1^{x'}\frac{g^Q}{\sqrt{1-g}}dg=\frac{b}{q-1}\int_1^{x'}g^Q(1-g)^{-1/2}dg
$$

where $x'=\left(\frac bx\right)^{1-q}$.

Let $$\overline B(x;a,b)=\int^1_x t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-1}dt$$ be the upper incomplete beta function.

Then,
$$
\frac{b}{q-1}\int_1^{x'}g^Q(1-g)^{-1/2}dg=\frac{b}{1-q}\cdot \overline B(x';Q+1,\frac12)=\frac{b}{1-q}\cdot \overline B\left(\left(\frac bx\right)^{1-q};\frac1{q-1},\frac12\right)
$$

As a result,
$$\color{red}{\int_b^x \frac{1}{\left(1-(b/r)^{1-q}\right)^{1/2}}\,dr=\frac{b}{1-q}\cdot \overline B\left(\left(\frac xb\right)^{q-1};\frac1{q-1},\frac12\right)}$$

which should be the best closed form you can obtain.

Luckily, the integral converges for any $b,x,q$ in your specified range. Although there is a pole near $1$, the integrand diverges as $(1-t)^{-1/2}$ near there and the integral does converge by p-test.

Comment: This should confirm my earlier calculations. Thanks a lot. I will have to double check mine if it coincide yours.

Comment: @user583893 If you don’t find any problem, please kindly accept this answer!

Comment: Hi there, i think that should be $\frac{b}{1-q} B(1-(\frac{x}{b})^{q-1};\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{q-1})$. Because after your incomplete beta function, you must still do substitution to express the correct limits (i.e. from 0 to x' not 1 to x')

Comment: @user583893 But what I defined is the upper incomplete beta function which is not usually implemented in computer systems. Are you sure that you used the correct function?

Comment: Sorry but i am not used to "upper" incomplete beta function. I just needed to re-express the integral to look like the incomplete beta function with limits 0 to x' because that's what i used to.

Comment: @user583893 Yes, then your form is correct. Hope I've somewhat helped you!

Comment: Thanks a lot because your solution reminded me of my previous calculations.

Comment: Hi @Szeto, I think the Beta function does not hold since $\frac{1}{q-1}<0$ for my range of $q$. For $B(x,a,b)$ to hold,  $Re(a)>0$ and $Re(a)>0$.

Comment: @user583893 This is the incomplete Beta function. it holds even when the first argument is negative.

Comment: Are you sure? Does $B(x,a,b)$ still hold even for negative values of $b$?

Comment: Ah yes, I get it now. Thanks @Szeto. Is there a way to invert an incomplete beta function?